# How to handle ImageView setImageResource difference from setImageDrawable

Tags: android, imageview

So after tons of frustrations with trying to stretch my image properly to width I realise my real problem is that setImageResource acts different from setImageDrawable (which I'm trying to use). XML below gives me perfect width, aspect ratio stretched image with setImageResource but with setImageDrawable the image is not stretched to the width, any suggestions to how I should handle the problem? I use setImageDrawable because I get the image from the internet alternatives are welcome :)

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Oh and I've tryed scaletype, the one giving best results was centercrop but it crops which isn't desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fix I've found is to use a bitmap as setImageBitmap apparently works similar to setImageResource. I'm still open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is really stale but in case anyone comes across it, the problem has to do with not quite a bug, but a bad implementation decision in versions of Android prior to 18.  If you target 18+ you probably won't see this issue.  However I'm currently targeting enterprise owned tablets at 16.

The solution is to create a superclass of ImageView that overrides onMeasure to enforce the aspect ratio:

```
class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        float iwidth  = (float) View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        float swidth  = (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        float sheight = (float) getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
        float iheight = sheight / swidth * iwidth;
        setMeasuredDimension((int)iwidth, (int)iheight);
    }
}
```

In your layout:

```
<com.mypackage.MyImageView layout_width="match_parent" etc... />
```

If you target Android 18+ adjustViewBounds should work as expected.

Comment: Targetting Android 22 and your fix helped me.

Answer (score 0):

you just make change in xml ImageView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_hight="fill_parent"

Comment: No doesn't work try again :) I don't know if the problem ca be related to my imageview being inside a relativelayout which is inside a scrollview. The problem still remains that the setImageResource works and the setImageDrawable doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your image view's width is fill_parent so if your image's width is not enough then it will be stretched.If you dont want to use fill_parent just replace the width "wrap_content".

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: I want it stretched, that's whole my headache.

Comment: before calling setImageDrawable just make a drawable from the image and set its width.

Comment: That might work but seems like more work than using bitmaps, I think the bitmap will be the way to go.